# What's the best R function for calculating probability?

Tags: r, probability

The question I'm trying to answer is as follows: "A box contains 15 red marbles and 5 blue marbles. 10 marbles are drawn without replacement. What is the chance at least 2 of them will be red?"
What functions in R would help me solve this?
I don't need an answer to the question itself, rather a function in R that will help me solve it!

Comment: depends on the distribution, `?Binomial` or `?Normal`, etc

Comment: The probability is one. Randomly select 10 marbles would always having at least two marbles are red because even if we assume five blue marbles are selected, the other five marbles will be red and will meet the criteria. Not to mention other possibilities.

Comment: And if in the future you have a need that isn't a "trick question" I recommend you look at a package called `DescTools` which even has a nice vignette on combinatorics, since this problem is more about combinations and permutations than it is strictly about probability distributions

Answer (score 1):

I have a code to run simulation to calculate the probability. However, as I mentioned in the comment. The example you gave will always lead to 1, which is not exciting.

```
# Generate a vector containing 15 red marbles and 5 blue marbles
box <- c(rep("red", 15), rep("blue", 5))

# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(124)

# Size of sampling
N <- 10

# A function to run simulation, taking N marbels without replacement
sim_fun <- function(x) sample(box, size = N)

# Number of simulation
S <- 10000

# Run the simulation S times
sims <- replicate(S, expr = sim_fun(), simplify = FALSE)

# Calculate the proportion that at least two marbles are red
mean(sapply(sims, function(x){
  sum(x == "red") >= 2
}))
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to simuate you can calculate exactly with a few `r` functions.

```r
library(DescTools)

# build a vector with the right marbles
marbles <- c(rep("Red", 15), rep("Blue", 5))

# Our denominator is the total possible ways we
# can draw ten marbles no replacement orde doesn't matter
# CombN from DescTools gives us that number
CombN(marbles, 10, repl = FALSE, ord = FALSE)
#> [1] 184756

# CombSet generates all the permutations
tail(CombSet(marbles, 10, repl = FALSE, ord = FALSE))
#>           [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]   [,10] 
#> [184751,] "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue"
#> [184752,] "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue"
#> [184753,] "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue"
#> [184754,] "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue"
#> [184755,] "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue"
#> [184756,] "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue"

# We'll put all those combinations in a matrix called x
x <- CombSet(marbles, 10)

# We can search for all rows that have "Red" at least twice
# with x[rowSums(x == "Red") >= 2, ]
tail(x[rowSums(x == "Red") >= 2, ])
#>           [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]   [,10] 
#> [184751,] "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue"
#> [184752,] "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue"
#> [184753,] "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue"
#> [184754,] "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue"
#> [184755,] "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue"
#> [184756,] "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue" "Blue"

# So the total possibilities are
nrow(x)
#> [1] 184756

# And the number that meet the condition is
nrow(x[rowSums(x == "Red") >= 2, ])
#> [1] 184756

# to calulate the probability
# we put nrow(x[rowSums(x == "Red") >= 2, ]) over
# nrow(x)
nrow(x[rowSums(x == "Red") >= 2, ]) / nrow(x)
#> [1] 1

# The probability is 1

### a more reasonable game
# same marbles
marbles <- c(rep("Red", 15), rep("Blue", 5))

# Draw 5 without replacement what is the probability
# we'll draw exactly two blue

totalpossiblepicks <- CombN(marbles, 5, repl = FALSE, ord = FALSE)

matrixofpicks <- CombSet(marbles, 5)

desiredoutcomes <- nrow(matrixofpicks[rowSums(matrixofpicks == "Blue") == 2, ])
# calculate probability
desiredoutcomes / totalpossiblepicks
#> [1] 0.2934727
```